# How to openRow (leftSwipe) dynamically in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios, mobile-application

I am using react-native-base to swipable list. As per the code below, Every row will have "md-remove-circle" icon and I want to open row (leftSwipe) by clicking on the "md-remove-circle" icon. It is possible to openRow dynamically by function call ?

```
<List
          dataSource={this.ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.listViewData)}
           renderRow={ (data, secId, rowId, rowMap) => 

            <ListItem style={{borderBottomWidth: 1,marginLeft: 0, backgroundColor : data.rowBg}}>

              <Left>
              { 
                this.state.rmvCircle && 

                <Icon onPress={()=>this.openCurrenRow()} style={{color:'red'}} name="md-remove-circle" />
              }

                <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.redir(data)}>
                  <Text>
                    {data.text}
                  </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>  
              </Left>
            </ListItem>}


            renderRightHiddenRow={(data, secId, rowId, rowMap) =>
              <Button
                full
                danger
                onPress={_ => this.clearNotificationPrompt(secId, rowId, rowMap, data.logId,'single')}
                style={{
                  flex: 1,
                  alignItems: "center",
                  justifyContent: "center"
                }}
              >
                <Icon active name="trash" />
              </Button>} 
              disableRightSwipe
              leftOpenValue={this.state.leftOpenValue}
              rightOpenValue={this.state.rightOpenValue}
           />
```

Comment: you are already calling a function on leftSwipe, right?

Comment: I have edited my question I applied disableLeftSwipe. I am doing this.state.rmvCircle : true from other function, When rmvCircle will true, "md-remove-circle" will show at left on every row, And on any icon click I want to make Trash icon open for that particular row.

Comment: What you wrriten for `openCurrenRow()`

Comment: empty inside this function for now, But I have to add logics inside this function to open row. That's why I wrote there

Comment: Is it possible to do that ?

Comment: It's possible I guess... could you create a sandbox of your code

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change the state of this.state.leftOpenValue to true or false

```
yourFunctionName () {
 this.setState({leftOpenValue: true})
}
this above will dynamically open up the leftOpenValue
```

Comment: leftOpenValue =>it accept integer rather then Boolean.

Comment: And how would it know to get open-row for any particular row (which row "md-remove-circle" has been clicked)